# Using an image URL for the DOM style cursor property

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, cursor

I am trying to use a custom cursor icon under certain conditions in my React application.
Assuming that the following works as expected:

```
this.element.style.cursor = 'crosshair'
```

How can I use an .svg image instead of one of the native cursor values?

Syntax that hasn't worked:

```
this.element.style.cursor = '../relative/path/icon.svg'
```

```
this.element.style.cursor = ['../relative/path/icon.svg']
```

```
this.element.style.addProperty('cursor', '../relative/path/icon.svg', 'auto')
```

Its probably either a simple path or syntax issue, but any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor for syntax and note there are size limits on the cursor and you need a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the string needs to be in [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()) format:

```
this.element.style.cursor = 'url(../relative/path/icon.svg), pointer';
```

In React you might need a template literal to evaluate the path:

```
this.element.style.cursor = `url(${myURLVarialble}), pointer`;
```

You can also define the custom cursor in a CSS class and apply the class to the element.